# Sorting a measure in tableau- based on a column

Tags: tableadapter, tableau-api

I want to sort a column which is measure
input:
a 1

a 2

b 4

c 1

d 2

then output should be

b 4

a 3

d 2

c 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really easy,not sure what complexity you find here.

just drag your `dimension` and a`ggregate` your `measure` then click the sort by `descending`

To get your output :

[image]

And if you mean there is only 1 column with values like `a1`,`a2`,`b4`...
you could make use of `LEFT` and `RIGHT` functions and get your final output.